# Read from a tar.gz file without saving the unpacked version

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, tar, gzip

I have a tar.gz file saved on disk and I want to leave it packed there, but I need to open one file within the archive, read from it and save some information somewhere.

```
File structure:
base_folder
  file_i_need.txt
  other_folder
  other_file
```

code (it is not much - I tried 10mio different ways and this is what is left)

```
def self.open_file(file)
    uncompressed_file = Gem::Package::TarReader.new(Zlib::GzipReader.open(file))
uncompressed_file.rewind
end
```

When I run it in a console I get

```
<Gem::Package::TarReader:0x007fbaac178090>
```

and I can run commands on the entries. I just haven't figured out how to open an entry and read from it without saving it unpacked to disk. I mainly need the string from the text file.

Any help appreciated. I might just be missing something...

Comment: `TarReader` is `Enumerable`, returning [`Entry`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/Gem/Package/TarReader/Entry.html). So, you’d need to `uncompressed_file.detect { |f| f.fullname == 'base_folder/file_i_need.txt' }.read`.

Comment: thanks. makes total sense - no idea why I didn't get to that myself. If you want the points post it as the answer :)

Comment: Since the problem was solved, I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`TarReader` is `Enumerable`, returning [`Entry`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/Gem/Package/TarReader/Entry.html).

That said, to retrieve the text content from the file by it’s name one might

```
uncompressed = Gem::Package::TarReader.new(Zlib::GzipReader.open(file))
text = uncompressed.detect do |f| 
  f.fullname == 'base_folder/file_i_need.txt'
end.read
#⇒ Hello, I’m content of the text file, located inside gzipped tar
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got stuck!